# Is it possible in gRPC to use a server to perform Asynchronous and Synchronous service at the same time with different client

Tags: c++, grpc, grpc-c++

Is it possible to perform Asynchronous and synchronous operation using single server in grpc. Let me elaborate my question clearly i have a server and two client one client is performing synchronous service and another client is performing asynchronous service.So how both the client access the server at the same time?

i just try combaining synchronous and asynchronous API in proto and combain the server and client code. But it is performing in the way like asynchronous is performing after synchronous operation

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to access the same gRPC server with both synchronous and asynchronous clients?

If so, this is possible. The server does not care about, or even know about, the threading model of the client.

Comment: thanks for your replay. How can we implement this on the server side? Did we need to create call data() for each time (taking reference greeter_async_server.cc). If it is possible can you please elaborate on your answer or share some sample code for the same.